# A function with polynomially bounded derivatives is polynomially bounded?

Tags: derivatives

I have a question.
If a function has polynomially bounded derivatives (of all order) then then function is polynomially bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be differentiable function and $p$ a polynomial with $|f'(x)|\le p(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Let $P$ be an anti-derivative of $p$ (also a polynomial). Consider $x_0$ with $p(x)\ge0$ for all $x\ge x_0$. Then for $x\ge x_0$, we have $$f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\,\mathrm dt\le \int_{x_0}^x p(t)\,\mathrm dt=P(x)-P(x_0).$$
A similar bound holds for $-f(x)$ as well as near $-\infty$. The compact interval between these tow cases doesn't hurt ither.

Answer (score 0):

Even one derivative polynomially bounded is enough, because if $f'(x) \le  c x^p$
for $x > N$,

$$ f(x) \le f(N) + \int_N^x c t^p\; dt = f(N) + \frac{c}{p+1} (x^{p+1} - N^{p+1})\ \text{for}\ x > N $$